# How can I search matching values or items selected from a useform multiselect listbox from a sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new in excel-VBA. I have two(2) multiselect listbox in a userform. listbox#1 contains a list of items that I retrieve from a range of cells in a worksheet(ex.Sheet1). I would like to add a new list of items to listbox#2 if the values selected in listbox#1 matches the cell value from sheet2 column A. For instance, If the selected items from listbox#1 matches the value in a cell from column A then get the values of the adjacent column (Column C) and add it to listbox#2. NOTE: sometimes there are duplicate values in column A I want to get all of the values from the adjacent column ("C") too.

Thank you!

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my code so far.

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long
        
    Set ws = Sheets("Class_DataSheet")'from Sheet2
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For i = 2 To ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row Step 1
    
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("A" & i)
    Set rng2 = ws.Range("C" & i)
    
    With Schedulefrm.SchedDateTimelist ' Listbox#2
        For k = 0 To Schedulefrm.ClassIDList.ListCount - 1 'ClassIDList is listbox#1
            If Schedulefrm.ClassIDList.Selected(k) Then
                If Schedulefrm.ClassIDList.List(k) = rng1.Value Then
                    .Clear
                    .AddItem rng2.Value 'it adds only one last value of the column ("C") from sheet2
                     For j = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                            .Selected(j) = True
                        Next j
                End If
            End If
        Next k
    End With
    
    Next i
```

Comment: Don't use Excel for what should be done with a database. You should look into Microsoft Access for this project.

Comment: If you really want this to be efficient then you should grab your entire Excel range into an array and do your lookups on the array. You could write a function that looks up each listbox item one at a time and return that result then move on to the next listbox item. This breaks down your task into smaller chunks instead of trying to think about the big picture solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

**edited** after OP's clarifications about duplicates handling

Option Explicit

```
Private Sub ClassIDList_Change()
    Dim k As Long
    Dim dataIDRng As Range, found As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With Worksheets("Class_DataSheet") 'from Sheet2
        Set dataIDRng = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    End With

    With Schedulefrm
        .SchedDateTimelist.Clear
        With .ClassIDList
            For k = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(k) Then
                    Set found = dataIDRng.Find(What:=.List(k), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
                    If Not found Is Nothing Then
                        firstAddress = found.Address '<~~ store the found cell address
                        Do '<~~ start a loop through all range cells to find those matching the selected item. it'll wrap around to the beginning of he range once reached its end
                            Schedulefrm.SchedDateTimelist.AddItem found.Offset(, 2)
                            Set found = dataIDRng.FindNext(found) '<~~ look for next matching cell
                        Loop While found.Address <> firstAddress '<~~ loop until you hit the first found cell again
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: OP needs the dups added to the list too. That's how I read it anyway. It may have a different date I think. A good solution anyway :)

Comment: @user3598756 lol I don't know why you tried to flatter me before, you're far better than I^^

Comment: @findwindow I didn't flatter you (whatever it might mean). I simply like your way of thinking and approaching code problems.

Comment: lol so I was just flattering myself XD Well, I still think you're better^^

Comment: @MichaelZ I do think OP'S question is to be refined. Let's wait for Jay's feedback

Comment: Thank you user3598756 it worked! However, Michael Z you are right I should go an Access database approach. In fact, the data from the spreadsheet

Comment: cont: The data from the spreadsheet I am using is pulling it from a Access database that I created but I very new in using Access and I still learning on how to create Query, relationships and etc. I am connecting to the database my opening a new ADODB connection.

Comment: user3598756: Regarding the dups, I assume it means Duplicates? the duplicates are in column A only (dataIDRng = .Range("A2:A")) but the dates are all different. I hope I explained it well.

Comment: Thank you again Michael Z, Findwindow and user3598756!

Comment: Sorry guys, I just realize that the code above worked however it only adds the first data found in range A2:A. Is there a way that it continues to add the data to the listbox everytime it founds a match? for example: column1 jay; jay;mike;and jay then in column2 its 1;2;3;4. so if I found "jay" I should get 1;2 and 4. Thank you in advance.

Comment: then you want to add a loop through `dataIDRng` cells and find out all those matching the selected value.  see edited answer where I used a rather consolidated technique you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through your first ListBox and pass the value into this function.

The second argument should only be the column range you are looking for values in. The function does an offset from there.

```
Public Sub FindMyStuff(FindWhat As String, dataRange As Range, ByRef listbox As listbox)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In dataRange
        If cell.Value = FindWhat Then
            listbox.AddItem cell.Offset(0, 2)
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: @findwindow This isn't the most efficient way especially when compared to user3598756 answer, but this breaks the process down a little bit that will make it easier to read and maintain.

Comment: It's an approach I wouldn't have considered or even crossed my mind^^ So for that alone, it's worth merit.

Comment: @findwindow thanks :) - the concept is correct and will work, but I didn't test the code for his needs.It looks like it would run fine though, right?

Comment: lol I didn't even read OP's requirements XD Just studying how others' write code ^_^; Edit: I learned to code on TI-Basic so I am extremely poor with OOP. Writing functions and passing arguments is something I like to work on.