# Deleting Rows Based on Multiple Cell Values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete rows that are empty in Column A and not empty in Column B in an Excel sheet.

I need to keep the rows that have values in A, however I also need to keep the rows that have nothing in them (they are my spacers).

I tried this:

```
Sub DoStuffIfNotEmpty()
    If Not IsEmpty(Colmuns("B").Value) Then
        ActiveCell.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Which deleted my spacers.

I tried this:

```
Sub QuickCull()
    On Error Resume Next
    Columns("A").Columns("B").SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Which deleted one of the rows with this criteria.

I tried this:

```
Sub delete_Me()
Dim LastRow As Long, x As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Not IsEmpty(Colmuns("B").Value) And _
    Columns("A").Value Then
        Rows(x).Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Which does nothing.

Comment: I wrote an answer to another question where the solution (I believe) is to use the Advanced Filter feature.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490980/check-if-a-cell-value-exists-in-column-return-a-value-in-the-same-row-but-diffe/37491109  One could use this to build a second list with only the records you wanted.

Comment: Do you have column header labels in row 1 that you want to keep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub removeRows()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rowNum As Integer
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For rowNum = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Range("B" & rowNum).Value <> "" And Range("A" & rowNum).Value = "" Then
        Rows(rowNum).Delete
    End If
Next rowNum

End Sub
```

As was pointed out by @findwindow and @Jeeped, the loop should run from the bottom row to the top.  My mistake.  Also I adjusted the LastRow to be counted using Column "B".

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have a quick question. So it removes what it needs to, but in order to wipe all the (I call them) detail lines, I need to run the macro a few times. Do you happen to know why that might be?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly using Count or counta as well

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim LstRw As Long, Rng As Range
    LstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    For x = LstRw To 1 Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 2))) = 0 Then Rows(x).Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx). Filter for blanks on column A and non-blanks on column B. After checking to see if there are rows to delete, delete them.

```
Sub del_blankA_valueB()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .UsedRange.Cells
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="="
            .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.CountA(.Columns(2))) Then
                    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you know what I wanted to say =P